# How to properly create and reference a managed policy with AWS CDK?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-cdk

I am trying to create managed policies from JSON and reference them in roles using AWS CDK with .NET. I have 2 stacks - PolicyStack and IAMStack. Before the upgrade there was only the IAMStack, that took care of role creation, but now I need to add the option of policy creation. I have a problem understanding exact syntax of policy creation in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.IAM.ManagedPolicy.html#Amazon_CDK_AWS_IAM_ManagedPolicy__ctor_Amazon_JSII_Runtime_Deputy_DeputyBase_DeputyProps_), but so far the program compiles and the policies get created. Currently I create policies like following:

```cs
foreach (var _policy in _policies) {        // JSON holding info about policies
    var newPolicy = new ManagedPolicy(this, _policy.PolicyName, new ManagedPolicyProps {
        Statements = new[] {
            new PolicyStatement(new PolicyStatementProps {
                Effect = Effect.ALLOW,
                Resources = _policy.Resource.ToArray(),
                Actions = _policy.Action.ToArray()
            })
         }
     });
}
```

The first problem is that the name of the created policy is different than specified. For example if the name specified is `s3-access-policy` the actual policy name ends up something like `PolicyStack-s3accesspolicy-Zlasdf9IfnA`.

The other problem is that the code that attaches the managed policies to roles throws the error `Policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/PolicyStack-s3accesspolicy-Zlasdf9IfnA does not exist or is not attachable`. The PolicyStack is executed before the IAMStack and the policy is created, however I have noticed that the only difference between the ARN in the error and the policy's actual ARN is the user - in the error the user is `aws` and in the actual ARN the user is a user's ID i.e. `123456789235`. Policies are attached to roles using

```cs
    role.AddManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.FromAwsManagedPolicyName(policy_name));
```

I have two questions:

- Why does the name of the policy change?
- Why can't I reference the managed policies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not confident with .NET but I am so with AWS CDK, I'll try to give you some information.

Let's start with ID's.

> - Why does the name of the policy change?

In CDK whenever you are instantiating a Construct object you [must](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_init) always pass at least 2 parameters: the scope and the (construct) id.
As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html) :

> This identifier [construct id, editor's note], like all identifiers, only needs to be unique within the scope in which it is created, which is the first argument when instantiating a construct object.

Basically, you are declaring an ID to the Construct object but not the policy name as you would. In order to do that you should explicitly give a value to the property `ManagedPolicyName` while instantiating the property interface `IManagedPolicyProps` as you did.

A side note is that whenever a resource name is not given to a Construct Object, then CDK automatically assigns a physical name (this is exactly your case) to provide a unique reference to the object. A full explanation is in the linked docs under the section Unique Id

Concerning the other error:

> - Why can't I reference the managed policies

You are calling the wrong method here. An *AWS Managed Policy* is a Policy but is not the kind of policy you just created. The latter is called *Customer managed* to distinguish from the former type that is maintained by AWS (dynamically updated in time) while your policies are possibly maintained by yourself.
[image]

To solve it, you must use this method  `FromManagedPolicyName`.

I suggest you an alternative, if the two Stacks are in the same AWS CDK App, then you [can also use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names) a reference to the object created in the first stack.